# Hodge Star in Jost's Book

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, hodge-theory

I am currently reading Jost's Book "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis" (Sixth Edition).

In 3.3 on page 103, he writes:

> From the rules of multilinear algebra, it follows easily that if $A$ is a $d\times d$-matrix, and if $f_1,\dots,f_p \in V$, then
> $$ \ast(Af_1\wedge\cdots\wedge Af_p)=(\operatorname{det}A)\ast(f_1\wedge\cdots\wedge f_p)$$

Here $V$ is a $d$-dimensional real vector space.
I cannot help myself but thinking that this formula is wrong. It fails already in the case where $d=3$ and $p=2$. Am I getting something extremely wrong here or is this formula indeed incorrect?

My problem is, that I feel that this formula is wrong on the one hand but on the other hand this is already the sixth edition of his book, so I guess if it would be wrong indeed, somebody would have found this out already.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I know that the statement is true whenever $d=p$, I am more curious about the case when they are not equal.

Comment: It makes sense when $d=p$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question was more about the case when they are not equal.

Comment: Have you a counterexample for $d=3$, $p=2$?

Comment: I think this is false. Take a two-dimensional space, the projection onto the first axis, and the first coordinate vector. Then the LHS is the second coordinate vector while the RHS is zero.

Comment: **I'm an amateur**, so take my advice with a grain of salt. I also doubt this for $p < d$. Consider $V = \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $\mathsf{e}_1,\ldots,\mathsf{e}_d$ be the standard basis for $ \mathbb{R}^d$. Then consider $\ast(A\mathsf{e}_1\wedge\cdots\wedge A\mathsf{e}_p) = \ast(\mathsf{a}_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathsf{a}_p)$, where the $\mathsf{a}_i$ are the columns of $A$. **Not all of the columns of $A$ appear in this expression, so there is not enough information to compute $\det(A)$.**

Comment: This also fails for some permutation matrices; at least if we take basis vectors and a matrix that doesn’t fix all of them. (Assuming $p<d$.)

Comment: I was initially confused, but it seems that the conclusion from this equality: "In particular, this implies that the star operator does not depend on the choice of positive orthonormal basis in V , as any two such bases are related by a linear transformation with determinant 1." is correct if one considers only the case $p=d.$